# Bootstrap 3 Navbar won't toggle (have checked existing solutions, still won't toggle collapse when clicked on)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap website li tags will condense on the mobile version. 
but when I click on the toggle button the navbar won't load up on the mobile version.

here's the html/css code with javascript references:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Welcome to our website</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 
</head>
 
<body>

 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="main-navbar">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
   <a href="" class="navbar-brand">FaceTheMusic</a>
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
   target=".navHeaderCollapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   </div>
  
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


<div id="navPlayer" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<br /> <br/> <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> 
This is a test <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />
This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />
This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br /> 
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />
This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />This is a test <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> 
This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br /> This is a test <br />
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra space between data- target

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-
        target=".navHeaderCollapse">
```

It should be

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
```

IF you fix that, it should work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/5fx9qwuy/1/

Comment: I have changed it in my file but it still wont work. Do you have any other solutions to recommend.

Comment: Hm...that is strange. The only thing I can think of are your sources. All I did in jsfiddle was copy your code and remove the extra spaces. You can try that yourself. The sources I included in jsfiddle was from google library which should be the same as what you download from bootstrap

Comment: I have found the bug. the file is saved as .php as soon as I save it as .html it works.

Comment: I don't see how that can be an issue with php unless you use a particular framework

Comment: I'm running on mac using xampp os x server that's why, I think anyway

Comment: Hm...i cannot help you then, since i dont have mac. You can bring it up with another question then and hopefully someone will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

**Abdullah Haider** Hi there.
A couple of things why this is not working for you.
In the main **nav** code block you are missing some `classes` and a `id`.
The div just above the `<ul>`you should include this id... `id="navbar"`.

Plus you have all you **JS** at the top of you page, try to always place your JS links at the very bottom of your page.

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k107mdw/)** of your code.

Try to use this as a starting point for your **navbar**.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Have a look through this code and your navbar code to see the changes.

Hope this helps to get you started.